Training a good ringtone generator - tips on VAE
Since last weekend I have been trying to build a ringtone generator. Basically my input dataset is a collection of 476 MIDI ringtones which has a lot of variety from simple ringtones to more elaborate melodies. Some of them are multi instrumental and not just single piano rolls.
I chose 3 models - LSTM, UNet and VAE. When I tested with LSTM (4 cell arch) it seems to produce a 3 second clip which basically sounds like someone played all the keys in the piano at once. UNet with 2 layers of encoder and decoder also gave a similar result but a bit more extended. VAE however gave something like a jazzy melody which was 10 seconds long.
I want to know how can one work with these ringtones so that more melody comes out from the results. I am aware that dataset is very small, so just wanted to know if augmentation or more samples would help.
Note: All the generated results are single vector piano rolls, so it is not multi-instrumental. I have tried experimenting with hyper parameters like learning rates, batch sizes, layers etc and losses are pretty low in all the cases. Might be prone to overfitting(especially LSTM and UNet variants) but not fully sure.
